# Deleted all my commit after bad manipulation in GitHub

Tags: github

After a bad manipulation I deleted all the commit of my git.
Can I recover all my commit ?

It's for a university project and the professor wants to see our work throughout the project.
I don't know if my problem become after the command
git pull --rebase origin master
or
git reset --mixed origin/master
or another comand...

Someone can help me please

Comment: Please explain what you did to delete all commits. Is the project lost from GitHub, or just from your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first you [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): if your work was committed (before any git pull/reset command), you will be able to [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) (with Git 2.23+) any past commit.

The next step will be to see if you have added files to the index or not.

Anything not staged (added to the index) and not committed would be likely lost (except for disk recovery utilities, or local IDE history)